# Loosely coupling composite object nodes and their dependencies

Tags: c#, design-patterns, tree, composite

Lets say I have a set of conditional requirements that can be nested inside of each other in a tree like structure, but all of the requirements need to communicate with different subsystems to find out if they are fulfilled. For instance one requirement might check if a certain inventory item exists, one might check an object for a certain attribute, one might check an event system to see if a certain event has fired etc. How could you model this so that you can traverse the tree as a part-whole hierarchy but also allow each node to communicate with the subsystem it needs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should model the aggregation and later use dependency injection (see [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)) to require whichever object that should fulfill the desired functionalities.

Each node would be like a [*domain model*](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html).

Something like this:

```
public class A
{
    // You inject some service IServiceX
    public A(IServiceX serviceX) 
    {
        ServiceX = serviceX;
    }

    private IServiceX ServiceX { get; }

    // B is associated to A
    public B B { get; set; }

    // So you can do some stuff calling the whole ServiceX
    public void DoStuff()
    {
         ServiceX.DoWhatever();
    }
}

public class B 
{
    public B(IServiceY serviceY) 
    {
        ServiceY = serviceY;
    }

    private IServiceY ServiceY { get; }

    // C is associated to B
    public C C { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
         ServiceY.DoWhatever();
    }
}

public class C
{    
    public C(IServiceZ serviceZ) 
    {
        IServiceZ = serviceZ;
    }

    private IServiceZ IServiceZ { get; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
         IServiceZ.DoWhatever();
    }
}
```

Obviously, you could inject more than a service into some of these aggregates. Since each aggregate gets associated with other one, you should be able to traverse the tree too.

Comment: I meant the coupling of the subsystems to the node not the nodes in the tree.  I think dependency injection looks promising.  Does dependency injection allow for injecting an object that has already been instantiated or will it inject a new instance for each constructor or property?

Comment: @Adam1980 You can inject existing instances. Caslte Windsor can do it, I don't know if others also own this capability. For example `container.Register(Component.For<IService>().Instance(instance))`

Comment: @Adam1980 BTW probably you don't want to create the instance yourself, but use a bound lifestyle like Castle Windsor already offers too. See this https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#bound-to-nearest